# Using an array to change video.src

Tags: javascript

I've tried to get it to work for a couple of days now, reseached how to do it changed it over and over but it just wont work. Im either stupid or blind. I want to code a simple videoplayer... I thought it was easy enough for starters T_T

This is the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<script language="JavaScript" src="player.js"></script>
</head>

<body onkeydown="GetKey()" onload="VideoList()">

<div style="text-align:center">
  <img src="images/Magipoka.jpg" onclick="window.location='Magipoka.html'">
  <img src="images/puni.jpg" onclick="window.location='puni.html'">
  <br>
  <video id="currentVideo" autoplay="true" preload="auto"    onended="Playnext()"   
 onclick="goFullscreen('currentVideo'); return false" ;=""> 

  <source src="Magipoka.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
  <source src="Magipoka.ogv" type="video/ogv"> 
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video. 
  </video>
</div>

<div style="text-align:center"> 
   <button onclick="LoopToggle()">Loop</button>
   <button onclick="LoopToggleOff()">LoopOff</button>
   <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button> 
  </div>
  <script language="JavaScript" src="Body_Scripts.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

body js file:

```
var Video=document.getElementById("currentVideo"); 
var VideoCount = 0;
var source = new Array();   


function VideoList(){
    source[0].src = "Magipoka.ogv";
    source[1].src = "puni.ogv";
}

function playPause()
{ 
 if (Video.paused) 
 Video.play(); 
 else 
 Video.pause(); 
}

function LoopToggle(){
  if (Video.ended)
    Video.play();
    if(Video.loop="false")
      video.loop=true;
      else
      video.loop=null;
      }


function Repeat(){
    if(Video.ended)
    Video.paused();
    Video.play();
}

function Playnext(){
 Video.src = source[VideoCount];
    //alert(VideoCount);
VideoCount++;
 alert(source[1]);
}
```

header js file:

```
function goFullscreen(id) {
// Get the element that we want to take into fullscreen mode
var element = document.getElementById(id);

// These function will not exist in the browsers that don't support fullscreen mode yet, 
// so we'll have to check to see if they're available before calling them.

if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
  // This is how to go into fullscren mode in Firefox
  // Note the "moz" prefix, which is short for Mozilla.
  element.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
  // This is how to go into fullscreen mode in Chrome and Safari
  // Both of those browsers are based on the Webkit project, hence the same prefix.
  element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
}
// Hooray, now we're in fullscreen mode!
}
//-----------------
function GetKey(e) { var code; if (!e) var e = window.event; if (e.keyCode)
code = e.keyCode; else if (e.which) code = e.which; var character =
String.fromCharCode(code); setTimeout('ShowTree('+code+');',100);
}
function ShowTree(character, a){
if (character == 49){
window.location='puni.html' }
if (character == 50){
window.location='magiPoka.html' }
}
```

Comment: Could you reduce the test case down to the minimum required to produce the error, and provide the error? My first impression would be that `VideoList()` is assigning data to properties on Array indices that do not exist. i.e. use `source[0] = '...'` instead of `source[0].src = '...'`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This is _way_ too much code - which array are you talking about? What specifically does it do or not do that it is supposed to do? Please edit down the code to only the relevant bits.

Comment: I do not that you are improperly appending to your array.  `source[0].src = "Magipoka.ogv";` ought to be something like `source.push('Magipoka.ogv');` or by index `source[0] = 'Magipoka.ogv';`  So instead of setting `source[0].src` you should only be setting the string value as `source[0]`

Comment: You can actually eliminate the `VideoList()` function entirely and just initialize the array. `var source = ['Magipoka.ogv','puni.ogv'];`

Comment: In addition to what @MichaelBerkowski has provided, you might also like to have a look through [some Array documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: Omg I didn't even notice the .src no wonder it wasn't working.... thx a lot! That happens if u hack something together T_T but Im not good enough to code for real. Im doing this to get practice. THX a lot! The array is working fine now, but its still not playing the next video.  Ill try to get that to work myself. Do you know a good javascript, html/css editor? I need one that shows me typos and other bugs, im currently using notepad++ and sadly it has no such feature.